# same trigger alert stop in zabbix

Tags: zabbix

I'm using Zabbix 3.2; I've configured mail alert Action for all triggers. My question is,
Say trigger(A) alerts (Problem event) on escalation and returns to normal (Ok event alert) after few mintues. I need to stop the alert if same 'A' Trigger happened in next few mintues. How can it be possible?
I've tried with this documentation;
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/config/notifications/action/escalations

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit - do you want to alert only once if the problem frequently repeats - "flaps"?

Comment: for ex, A trigger - {host.cpu.util[,load].last()}>80; i receive 'problem' alert when cpu load > 80 and 'Ok' alert when goes < 80; If this same trigger (i.e again cpu load > 80 ) happens in next 15 mins; I dont want to receive alert. Is it possible? thks for ur consideration @R

Comment: Added an answer based on my understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems to be about preventing trigger flapping. In general, three methods are suggested:

- use [trigger functions](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/appendix/triggers/functions) - for example, instead of `last()` use `avg(15m)` - then the alerting will happen only after the average value for 15 minutes has exceeded the threshold. Other useful trigger functions might be `min()` and `max()`
- use hysteresis - this makes trigger fire at one threshold but resolve on another. Before Zabbix 3.2 that was done [in the trigger expression](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/triggers/expression#hysteresis); since Zabbix 3.2 there is a [separate "recovery" field](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/config/triggers/expression#hysteresis)
- use [action escalations](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/config/notifications/action/escalations) that do nothing at first, and only send an alert when the problem has been there for some period of time - for example, sending out the alert on the second or third step

All three methods achieve a similar outcome, but the key differences are:

- the first method - trigger functions - makes the trigger fire later, but reduces the number of events (the times trigger fires)
- the second method - hysteresis - makes the trigger fire at the same time as the "flappy" trigger, but delays the recovery event. It also reduces the number of events (the times trigger fires)
- the third method - delayed escalation steps - does not affect the trigger at all, it can keep on flapping. It will only alert if the problem is there for a longer time, though.

Hysteresis will usually alert when a trigger would have flapped; delayed escalation steps will ignore short-lived problems.

Complexity-wise, I'd usually go with the first method - it is the easiest to configure, the hardest to misconfigure and the easiest to understand. I'd go with one of the two other methods if I specifically needed the way they make events/alerts behave - those methods have a bit higher potential to be misconfigured or misunderstood.

Note that the item key reference in the comment is wrong - host is separated from key with colon, full key name is missing and the parameter is wrong. See [the agent key page](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent) in the manual for correct key syntax.

Comment: using hysteresis for delapyed recovery event helped me to solve the problem @Richlv